# filter records by year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Need to filter Articles by year using created_at field.

I got the links for years in articles like this:

**Article helper:**

```
  def artcles_by_years
    Article.uniq.pluck("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at)")
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
  <% for art in artcles_by_years do %>
    <%= link_to art %>
  <% end %>
```

it displays: `2009 2010 2011 2012`, sure, non-working links.

Question:

How would I build working links and query in controller to filter Articles by year, like pressing 2009 and return all articles created in 2009.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a scope to your model

```
scope :year, lambda{|year|
  where(" EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) = ? ", year ) if year.present?  
}
```

And use the scope in your controller:

```
@articles = Article.year(params[:year])
```

Display link as:

```
<%= link_to art, articles_path( :year => atr) %>
```